# TikTokApi has no atrribute get_instance

Tags: python, tiktok

I am trying to run some python code for several examples of TikTokApi but I always have the same error, **TikTokApi has no atrribute get_instance.** I am running Python 3.8.3rc1 in my machine and the simple code is:

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
verifyFp="my_code from cookie"
api = TikTokApi.get_instance(use_selenium=True, 
executablePath="/path/to/chromedriver",custom_verifyFp=verifyFp)
```

Any idea why it does not work? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code for V5. Read the [documentation](https://dteather.com/TikTok-Api/docs/TikTokApi.html#quick-start-guide)

```py
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
verifyFp="my_code from cookie"
api = TikTokApi(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver",custom_verify_fp=verifyFp)
```

More details on TikTokApi class [here](https://dteather.com/TikTok-Api/docs/TikTokApi/tiktok.html).

Comment: It resolved, partly. Thanks.

Comment: Should also be noted that @Diegoctn uses `use_selenium=True` in their post and that's been deprecated with V5.0.0 and only support for playwright will be officially supported in the future.